# Possible memory leak in Microsoft Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, memory-leaks

We have a document, its the largest in our company at 332 Kb and approx 220 pages, it has lots of tables and texts, no images at all though.

When we launch the document it is quick, adding or deleting rows or columns is quick just as you'd expect.

If we don't work in the document and the document is kept open for say 10 mins, and then we start editing in the document again it is extremely sluggish, copying and pasting rows or columns takes a long time and if we close and reopen the document again, everything is back to normal speed.

I haven't noticed the same issue in other documents. Will keep an extra eye out for that but for now it seems to be limited to just one document, any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

In general, to quickly get evidence of a memory leak, I look at whether the memory use for the process grows over time.  In your case, start Task Manager before Word and look at the Processes tab line for Word when you start it up with that troublesome file.  Keep an eye on it to tell whether your observed sluggishness is co-incident with rapid increase in memory use.

Comment: I checked that, noticed no change in memory or CPU utilization when launching word and working in the document directly and waiting 5 - 10 mins then working in it. I did see however the there are brief "Not Responding" in task Manager after i've not been working in the document. which is non-existent before. any other ideas?

Comment: Your title to your question asks whether there is a memory leak, and, in following the direction of my answer, you have good evidence that there is not a memory leak.  Therefore I have answered your question and I would appreciate if you clicked "accept" for the answer.  Troubleshooting the issue with your document in ways unrelated to memory leaking needs to be formulated as an answerable question (or several questions) to be appropriate for superuser.com.  Perhaps you can submit other questions.

Comment: For example, you can ask about the Task Manager not responding, but again, that's outside of the scope of your original question.  In looking it up by web search, it appears that there are multiple potential causes.